# What the difference between Google App Engine SDK and GWT SDK?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

They are installed together. Why the functional splitted in these two libraries? What does the splitting mean?

Comment: They don't necessarily install together. I've never had to install them together. The Google Plugin for Eclipse does support both. Is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Dave W. Smith Yes, it is. Probably I should look at GWT homepage before asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GWT is the Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and is a development toolkit to build Ajax websites without writing Javascript, but writing Java files that then gets compiled into Javascript.

If you program for Google App Engine you can decide, whether to use it or not. Also, if you want you can use GWT without app engine.